# Collect dumps during Windows power events

Tags: c++, windows, events, service, suspend

My application is a Win32 service which is registered for OS power events. When application gets callback of event, operations are performed depending on the type of the power event. During suspend/sleep event, our application tries to do specific networking jobs within 10 seconds before acknowledging the OS to continue with the suspend operation.

Under normal circumstances, my application does job successfully within 10 seconds. But sometimes, operations take too long and fail to complete with in 10 seconds. Application uses various Win32 API functions and I want to check which specific operation is causing the delay. Is there anyway to capture the dump of process hung in completion of jobs when system is going to suspend ?

I tried ProcMon, ProcExplorer, ProcDump but it didn't help. Any ideas on troubleshooting the issue other than adding logs in the code. Thanks.

Comment: You can use fake a power event within your program (so the system won't be going to sleep) then use normal debugging methods to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: Since it is networking related application, OS might do other things with the sockets, QOS service etc., Not sure if allowing the code flow through sleep actions (even when OS is not actually going to sleep) will help.

Comment: _adding logs in the code_ Sounds good to me.  How many do you think you need?  After all, capturing whatever happens to be currently executing when you,  ahem, take your dump might not tell you much - maybe the fatal delay was earlier and then there were a few milliseconds left to do a bit more before the rug was pulled out from under you.  So, maybe not _the_ delay, but the _delays_.

Answer (score 0):

[Windbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) tool available on Microsoft store is very helpful for capturing traces of any running process. My use case is to capture the trace of my process when OS hibernates. The trace can be used to time travel debug my application when OS was actually hibernating. A very useful tool from Microsoft. Tutorials on [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/windbg) on how to use the tool. Happy learning :)